# Why do matplotlib animations slow down when saving each successive frame?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I've noticed that when I use Matplotlib to make an animation, it takes progressively longer for each frame to be saved. I know this, because I introduced a timing check into `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py` inside the `print_figure` method of the `FigureCanvasBase class`:

```
        import time 
        t3=time.time() 
        result = print_method(
            filename,
            dpi=dpi,
            facecolor=facecolor,
            edgecolor=edgecolor,
            orientation=orientation,
            bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
            **kwargs)
        t4=time.time()
        print("LOG:       backend_bases          -----",t4-t3)
```

It took me some tracing to reach this point, and I've now hit the point of diminishing returns, since the print_method method seems to be determined dynamically.

Does anyone know why it takes significantly longer to save the 100th frame of an animation as opposed to the first?

I can avoid the problem by making several shorter animations and then stitching them together, but would prefer to understand why the problem exists in the first place.

I would understand how periodically needing to obtain more memory could introduce periodic delays for saving every nth image, but do not understand a steady, almost linear rate, increase in the time required to save each succeeding frame. Is this caused by some sort of compression each time a new frame is added to an animation? Is memory reallocated each time an animation grows? Or is it something else?

Comment: It'd be useful to post what versions you're using - I can't say I've experienced this, but then again I've never looked.

Comment: @Ajean - I'm using matplotlib 1.3.1 and Python 2.7.6